# Jssor Slides: I want to have multiple right arrows in slides

Tags: jssor

I am using  JSSOR Content Slider.

I want to have multiple right arrows in slides.. Like one will be the default one and other can we put it inside the content when user clicks the other arrow button it should take us to next slide..

Screenshot is also attached..

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please use api to do this job.

You can put any arrow in slide, and call api when user click.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {

            $AutoPlay: true,                                   //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $DragOrientation: 3                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

        function ArrowClickEventHandler() {
            jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(slideIndex);    //slideIndex is index of slide
        }

        $("#yourarrow").bind("click", ArrowClickEventHandler);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the response :).I have one questiong.. Do we need to add the above code in jssor.slider.js or in the document.ready function..